# Could Android EditText be target of XSS when loading a text?

Tags: android, security, android-edittext, xss

Is there any unsafe strings that may be placed into an `EditText` using `setText()` ?

Recently our app was subject to a security Scanner and EditTexts loading a text from another `EditText` raised an **Reflected XSS alert**.

I understand that this may be a vulnerability on webviews and websites in general that may alter the constructed HTML DOMS or even execute javascript.

I imagine the only way this may affect an android app is if the second EditText's text is processed later in a way the programmer isn't expecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any unsafe strings that may be placed into an EditText using setText() ?

Not really. As you note, there may be problems in how you use what the user fills into the `EditText`, but the `EditText` itself is not scriptable and so is not really a vehicle for attack.

> Recently our app was subject to a security Scanner and EditTexts loading a text from another EditText raised an Reflected XSS alert.

I am not aware of any XSS attacks relevant to Android native UIs (outside of `WebView`). After all, "XSS" is shorthand for "cross-site scripting", and there are no "sites" for Android native UIs.

IMHO, many online security scanners are [snake oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil).

Comment: I think it is possible to put unsafe strings in `EditText` which will be saved in a server-side database (considering the server does not check for SafeHTML). Then if the same application has a web client and after saving the information from the Android app, the application is launched via a web-browser, can't this be a potential threat of XSS?

Comment: @ReazMurshed: IMHO, the XSS flaw would be in the Web app (and the associated Web service that the Android app used), not in the Android app.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it could be a target of HTML Injection. EditText.setText(...) accepts a CharSequence object, and it could be a Spanned object (created from Html.fromHtml(...)). oversecured.com Android vulnerability scanner checks for such security flaws